# How can I flip a child object's sprite?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've changed the pivot point of my gun by adding a parental object for the pivot point and the child object for the gun sprite, and my gun is now turning around my player.

```
public class Gun : MonoBehaviour

{
private Rigidbody2D rb;
public Camera cam;
Vector2 mousePos;
Vector2 lookDir;
private float angle;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    lookDir = mousePos - rb.position;
    angle = Mathf.Atan2(lookDir.y, lookDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    rb.rotation = angle;
}
void Update()
{
    mousePos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
}}
```

but I have no idea how to acces child object's SpriteRenderer and flipY if gun's rotation is more than -90 and less than 90.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply store a reference to the `SpriteRenderer` either in the Inspector

```
// Drag your child object into the according slot via the Inspector within Unity
[SerializeField] private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
```

or using `GetComponentInChildren`

```
private void Awake ()
{
    if(! spriteRenderer) spriteRenderer = GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    lookDir = mousePos - rb.position;
    angle = Mathf.Atan2(lookDir.y, lookDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    rb.rotation = angle;

    spriteRenderer.flipY = -90 < angle && angle < 90;     
}
```